# Find $n$ , given $\sum_{i=1}^ni$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find the value of $n$ given $\sum_{i=1}^ni$. For example: If I have the number $5050$, how do I find that $n$ is $100$ here? Request your help.

Comment: Use the formula $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.

Comment: This question isn't very well phrased. I think you mean that you want to find $n$ given $k=\sum_{i=1}^ni$; i.e. you are told that $k$ is the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, and you want to find $n$. Is this right?

Comment: yes Matt . you are right. I am pretty new to this.I would like to find n given the sum of 1 to n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the arithmetic sum formula of

$\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2 $

Solve for $n$

Comment: Thanks jack / everybody!  That really helped.